# Passing lambda as an argument to a function with std::function parameter with an arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda, metaprogramming

Consider the next sample of the code:

```cpp
template <typename... TArgs>
void foo(std::function<void(TArgs...)> f) {
}

template <typename... TArgs>
class Class {
public:
    static void foo(std::function<void(TArgs...)> f) {
    }
};
```

Why can I do this:

```cpp
int main() {
// Helper class call
    Class<int, int>::foo(
        [](int a, int b) {}
    );
}
```

But I get a compile error doing this:

```cpp
int main() {
// Function call
    foo<int, int>(
        [](int a, int b) {}
    );
}
```

```
<source>:16:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo<int, int>(
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:4:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
    'std::function<void (int, int, TArgs...)>' against 
    '(lambda at <source>:17:9)'

void foo(std::function<void(TArgs...)> f) {
     ^
```

I just want to have a convenient way to use functions such as `foo`.

I've tried this:

```cpp
std::function<void(int, int)> f = [](int a, int b) {
    };

    foo<int, int>(f); // ok
```

And it worked. And this is ok. But I want to know if there is any way to use lambdas right in the function call, without creating a local function object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because of this: [Why is template parameter pack used in a function argument type as its template argument list not able to be explicit specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45318502)

When you call `foo<int, int>([](int a, int b) {});`, the pack `TArgs` is still deduced in case it needs to be extended. `std::function<void(TArgs...)>` cannot deduce anything for `TArgs...` with a lambda argument, so it gets deduced as an empty pack, which conflicts with the given `int, int`.

For `Class<int, int>::foo`, there is no template argument deduction since the template arguments are already given.

A fix for this is to put it in a non-deduced context:

```cpp
template <typename... TArgs>
void foo(std::type_identity_t<std::function<void(TArgs...)>> f) {
}
```

Or don't take a `std::function` at all:

```cpp
template <typename F>
void foo(F&& f) {
}
```

Comment: ..or wrap it in a class to prevent deduction as OP did alread ;)

Comment: ..or `static_cast<void(*)(std::function<void(int, int)>)>(&foo)([](int, int){});`